# Laravel migration. Problema con timestamp

Tags: laravel, date, timestamp, migration

Tengo una migration para una tabla de viajes. El código es el siguiente:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateToursTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('tours', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('operator_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('destino', 100);
            $table->timestamp('inicio');
            $table->timestamp('final');
            $table->integer('duracion')->unsigned();
            $table->text('detalles');
            $table->timestamps();
            /* El campo deleted_at */
            $table->softDeletes();
            /** La clave foránea para relacionar esta tabla con operators. */
            $table->foreign('operator_id')->references('id')->on('operators');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('tours');
    }
}
```

El problema aparece con el campo `final`. Lo quiero declarar como `timestamp`. Lo hago con el campo `inicio` y no da problemas, pero con el campo `final` me da un error:

```
   Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1067 Invalid default value for 'final' (SQL: create table `tours` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `operator_id` int unsigned not null, `destino` varchar(100) not null, `inicio` timestamp not null, `final` timestamp not null, `duracion` int unsigned not null, `detalles` text not null, `created_at`
timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null, `deleted_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')

  at C:\xampp\htdocs\viajes\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:664
    660|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    661|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    662|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    663|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 664|             throw new QueryException(
    665|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    666|             );
    667|         }
    668|

  Exception trace:

  1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1067 Invalid default value for 'final'")
      C:\xampp\htdocs\viajes\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:458

  2   PDOStatement::execute()
      C:\xampp\htdocs\viajes\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:458
```

El caso es que cojo la consulta que muestra el error, que es la siguiente:

```
create table `tours` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `operator_id` int unsigned not null, `destino` varchar(100) not null, `inicio` timestamp not null, `final` timestamp not null, `duracion` int unsigned not null, `detalles` text not null, `created_at`
timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null, `deleted_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
```

La ejecuto directamente en PHPMyAdmin y funciona sin problemas.

Si el campo `final` lo declaro como `date`, en lugar de `timestamp`, la migration se ejecuta sin problemas, pero, claro, no me queda el tipo de dato que quiero.

En el modelo `Tour.php` tampoco parece haber nada fuera de lugar:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use App\Operator;
use App\Customer;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Tour extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $table = 'tours';
    protected $fillable = [
        'operator_id',
        'destino',
        'inicio',
        'duracion',
        'final',
        'detalles'
    ];
    protected $dates = [
        'deleted_at'
    ];

    public function operator()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Operator::class);
    }

    public function customers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Customer::class);
    }
}
```

¿Alguien sabe a que puede deberse esto?
Gracias a todos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes declarar un valor por defecto para el campo `timestamp()` ayudandote del método `useCurrent()` de tal modo que tu migración quede así:

```
            $table->timestamp('inicio')->useCurrent();
            $table->timestamp('final')->useCurrent();
```

Al retornar de la base de datos un valor almacenado con estas dos columnas; deberías estar obteniendo algo similar a esto

```
#original: array:6 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "content" => "hello world"
    "inicio" => "2018-12-03 00:39:12"
    "fin" => "2018-12-03 00:39:12"
    "created_at" => "2018-12-03 00:39:12"
    "updated_at" => "2018-12-03 00:39:12"
  ]
```

Comment: Hola. Lo primero, gracias. Funciona. Y da igual que se añada el useCurrent() porque luego la factory ya se encarga de poner las fechas adecuadas.

Comment: Hola. Lo primero, gracias. Funciona. Y da igual que se añada el useCurrent() porque luego la factory ya se encarga de poner las fechas adecuadas.
Sin embargo, hay un problema. Si en la migration no pongo el campo "final", todo funciona bien. El campo "inicio" también está definido como timestamp() y en ningún momento me ha dado problemas, ni con useCurrent(), ni sin useCurrent().
En cambio, si quito el campo "inicio", el campo "final" no da problemas.
Parece como si hubiera un máximo de un campo timestamp sin useCurrent(), pero en la docu no se menciona este hecho.